# Is it possible to 'claim' a concession?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Underlying most OED definitions of the word *claim*, both noun and verb, is some notion of right or entitlement.

( An exception arises in the case of meaning 2c - the loosely used *he claimed to be Adolf Hitler*, or *he claimed that the speaker was drunk*. I am speaking here of the notion of claiming something for oneself, goods, money, services, rights, a status etc.)

In everyday parlance people frequently *claim* things for which they have no legal right. E.g. they may 'claim' some special privilege at work, because they consider themselves deserving of it.

One of the OED meanings of *entitlement* is:

> The belief that one is inherently deserving of privileges or special
>   treatment. Freq. in sense of entitlement.

So is it possible to *claim* something e.g. a *concession* for which one has no *right* or *entitlement* whatever? Does the action of *claiming* imply a considered *entitlement*?

On a further note on the matter of claim, sports commentators sometimes say, something like: *Joe Hart runs out of his goal and claims the ball*. Did he have an *entitlement* to the ball?

So, the question is ***Can you claim something for which you have no entitlement?***, or does the action of *claiming* set up a *de facto* ***considered entitlement***?.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20923/discussion-on-question-by-ws2-is-it-possible-to-claim-a-concession). Please see that chatroom before discussing this question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't know about others but I actually learned a lot about the word *claim* from that discussion. Shifting the whole lot, lock, stock and barrel, to 'chat', as if we had been shooting the breeze about the Wales v England Rugby International last night, does seem quite absurd.